# Nginx proxy_pass only works partially

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, php-7

I have the following setup

- Master server - call it `https://master.com`
- Slave server - call it `https://slave.com`

Both run Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04

On the master server I have created the following configuration block in my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file

```
location /test
{
 rewrite ^/test(.*) /$1 break;
 proxy_pass https://slave.com;
 proxy_read_timeout 240;
 proxy_redirect off;
 proxy_buffering off;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
}
```

A `service nginx reload` later on `master.com`and I can do the following

- Browse to `https://master.com/test` and view the output from `slave.com\index.php`.
- Browse to `https://master.com/test/test.txt`and see the text in the file `slave.com\test.txt`
- Browse to `https://master/com/test/test.jpg` and see the image in the file `slave.com\test.jpg`.

However, I cannot do any of the following

- Browse to `https://master.com/test/test.php`which instead of showing me the output from `https://slave.com/test.php` shows me a 404 error message
- Browse to `https://master.com/test/adminer/adminer.php`which instead of showing me the login screen for the Adminer instance on the slave, `https://slave.com/adminer/adminer.php`shows me the login screen for the Adminer instance on `master.com`i.e. `https://master.com/adminer/adminer.php`

This is clearly because I am missing something in my Nginx configuration on `master.com`. However, I am unable to see what that might be.

In the interests of completeness, here is my configuration on both servers:

**Ubuntu** - 16.04.3
**Nginx**  - 1.10.3
**PHP** - 7.0.22

I should explain why the `^~` is required since this is not clear from my original question.  I have another block setup to handle PHP scripts on `master.com`.

```
location ~ \.php$ 
{
 try_files $uri =404;
 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
 fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
 fastcgi_index index.php;
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
 include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Because of the way Nginx processes these directives this block takes priority when it comes to handling `.php` files and `master.com` ends up looking locally for `.php` scripts that are actually on `slave.com`. The only way to avoid this is to use `^~`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. Inside the block which handles `/test` your rewrite it and send it out of the block. The `proxy_pass` never actually happens because the new  URL doesn't have `/test` in it. Solution is simple, don't use rewrite

```
location /test/
{
 proxy_pass https://slave.com/;
 proxy_read_timeout 240;
 proxy_redirect off;
 proxy_buffering off;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
}
```

Appending `/` at the end of the location path and also the `proxy_pass` server will make sure what is after `/test/` is sent to your `proxy_pass` address

**Edit-1**

Here is a sample test case I had set before posting this answer.

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
server {
   listen 80;

   location /test1 {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
   }

   location /test2 {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81/;
   }

   location /test3/ {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
   }

   location /test4/ {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81/;
   }

}

server {
   listen 81;

   location / {
     echo "$request_uri";
   }
}
}
```

Now the results explains the difference between all 4 location blocks

```
$ curl http://192.168.33.100/test1/abc/test
/test1/abc/test

$ curl http://192.168.33.100/test2/abc/test
//abc/test

$ curl http://192.168.33.100/test3/abc/test
/test3/abc/test

$ curl http://192.168.33.100/test4/abc/test
/abc/test
```

As you can see in `/test4` url the proxied server only sees `/abc/test`

Comment: I have upvoted your answer because you rightly mention that I need the `/`terminating slash on `/test`. However, it is not quite the right answer.  The `rewrite`is required since on the destination server the resource requested is in document root, not in a subfolder `/test`.  I remembered that I had run into this issue a while ago and had got the [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212655/nginx-php-scripts-not-being-called-from-reverse-proxy](solution) on SO from @SeriousDron. To cut a long story short `location /test/`needs to be changed to read `location ^~/test/`and it all works!

Comment: @DroidOS, the answer is correct and you don't need a rewrite. You would need `^~` if there is another location which is handling your request because of the priority order. So if you check my edit you will see why and when a rewrite is not needed

Comment: This is such a pain.
When I use 'location /' it works
When I use 'location anything else it fails with 404 not found.
nginx sucks, I'm going to try something else