# Proxy_Pass using Nginx on windows

Tags: nginx

i am trying to use nginx for my hosted website on Azure using location. but even if i configure Nginx for google, i get a 404.

```
location /master 
{
proxy_pass http://www.google.com;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this thread for url details on `proxy_pass`

[Nginx proxy_pass only works partially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154405/nginx-proxy-pass-only-works-partially/46155347#46155347)

Your config

```
location /master 
{
   proxy_pass http://www.google.com;   
}
```

Send `/master` also as the part of the url. Which means you are trying to go to `http://www.google.com/master`. So this won't work as it is a 404. But if you add trailing `/` to both your locations

```
location /master/ 
{
   proxy_pass http://www.google.com/;   
}
```

The `/master` will not be sent as the request url. Also this would just work for a brief moment as you will get a 301 to https://www.google.com. So better is to use `proxy_pass https://www.google.com/;`

Comment: What issue do you face now?

Comment: I found that Nginx for Windows does not have mod_proxy module! :(